# How to calculate length of Clothoid segment?

Tags: calculus, geometry, fresnel-integrals

I want to calculate the length of a clothoid segment from the following available information.

1. initial radius of clothoid segment
2. final radius of clothoid segment
3. angle (i am not really sure which angle is this, and its not
   documented anywhere)

As a test case: I need to find length of a clothoid(left) that starts at $(1000, 0)$ and ends at approximately $(3911.5, 943.3)$. The arguments are: $initialRadius=10000$, $endRadius=2500$, $angle=45(deg)$.

Previously I have worked on a similar problem where initial radius, final radius, and length are given. So I want to get the length so I can solve it the same way.

I am working on a map conversion problem. The format does not specify what are the details of this angle parameter.

Please help. I have been stuck at this for 2 days now.

Comment: Please use MathJax to format your question.

Comment: Please use MathJax

Comment: Must be the angle between the extreme normals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic equation for a clothoid is  $R·L = A^2$ where **R** is radious, **L** is the length from the point where R=infinite and **A** is a constant (a scale factor). You can also write $L=\frac{A^2}{R}$

The length along the spiral (not a segment) between two points is $L= L_2 - L_1$

The local X-axis is the line tangent at R=inf, (and then $L=0$).

The angle $\phi$ from the X-axis to the tangent at a point $r=R_i$ is $\phi=\frac{L_i}{2R_i}=\frac{L_i^2}{2A^2}=\frac{A^2}{2R_i^2}$

So, $L_2-L1= \frac{A^2}{R_2} - \frac{A^2}{R_1} = A^2(\frac{1}{R_2}-\frac{1}{R_1})$

To get A you can use the angle at one point. For example, for the second point $(r=R_2$ and $\phi=\phi_2)$ you use $A^2= \phi_2·2·R_2^2$

Note that if the first point is R=inf, $L=0$ then the required length is
$L=A^2/R_2 = \phi_2·2·R_2$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

For a unit clothoid, of parametric equations

$$x=\int_0^t\cos t^2\,dt,\\y=\int_0^t\sin t^2\,dt,$$

the direction of the curve is given by

$$\tan\theta=\dfrac{\dot y}{\dot x}=\tan t^2,$$ and this is independent of scale.